# What is "M" in Hartley's law?

Tags: signal, ethernet, bandwidth, capacity

If [Hartley's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem#Hartley.27s_law) is:

$$ C = 2 B \log_2 M $$

I know this equation is part of calculating the capacity of a channel. I also understand that:

- \$C\$ is the digital bandwidth, in bits/second
- \$B\$ is the analog bandwidth, in hertz

But I do not understand the meaning of \$M\$. Could someone please explain it?

Comment: Huh? Seems you are lacking some context.

Comment: @PhilFrost Yes sorry for this easy and low quality question my major is not electrical engineering.

Comment: It's not easy. Where did you get this formula? You are wondering about "signal level", in what context? I mean, I could google "signal level" and summarize the results, but hopefully that's not what you want. Did you read it somewhere? Give us some context.

Comment: @PhilFrost on the computer networking books, which talk about TCP-IP layers. they divide network to four layers. Fisrt of them is physical layer. In this chapter when they want to talk about trasmission media and their capacity to have data. they talk about this formula and also shanon's formula.

Comment: Which chapter? What book? What is this formula? What do C, B, and M represent? Please *edit* the question to clarify.

Comment: It's too bad that the community reviewers don't recognize [Hartley's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem#Hartley.27s_law) when they see it. *M* is simply the number of distinguishable signaling states (usually voltage levels) that can be transmitted through the channel. See the Wikipedia article for how this relates to signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: @DaveTweed You should feel free to edit that into the question, then we can reopen it!

Comment: @DaveTweed Alternately, edit the title to be, "what is this equation?", then you can answer, and I don't think anyone will close the question because it clearly asks "what is [thing that reviewer does not know]?"

Comment: .....:) some one please answer this question.... My question is exactly is about Dave comment. So some one help. By the way my book is not english and not online to refer you to that.

Comment: @alex we need 4 more reopen votes, but I suspect we will get them. Just wait a bit.

Comment: ok sorry for giving your time. any way thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M is the number of distinguishable signaling states that the channel can pass, usually modeled as voltage levels.

For example, if you can transmit one of four different voltage levels over a pair of wires, you can send two bits at a time. Eight levels gives your 3 bits, and so on. This is why there's a log<sub>2</sub> relationship between levels and bits.

*Distingiushable* means that the receiver can reliably determine which of the levels the transmitter is sending. This means that the voltage offsets introduced by noise, intersymbol interference, etc. are less than the actual separation between the signaling levels at the receiver. As the noise level goes up, either you need to increase the overall signal level a corresponding amount, or you need to reduce the number of signaling levels you're using — either way, you increase the separation between the signaling levels.

Answer (score 3):

\$M\$ is the number of distinct messages that can be transmitted per symbol. The number of bits per symbol is then \$\log_2 M\$.

For example, if you take a simple protocol that is either high (5V) or low (0V), then \$M=2\$ and each symbol transmits one bit.

Or, perhaps instead you can signal one of four things:

- 0V (00)
- 1.67V (01)
- 3.33V (10)
- 5V (11)

Now \$M=4\$, and each time you do this you transmit 2 bits of information.

If you take an extreme example, say you have this signal going into a 32-bit analog-to-digital converter. Now there are in theory \$M = 2^{32} = 4294967296\$ possible messages, and each one transmits 32 bits of information.

Of course at some point your ability to resolve the difference between each message is limited by noise, and this is what the Shannon-Hartley theorem is about.